# Como saber quando a lei de Brooks se aplica?

Tags: projeto-de-software, gerenciamento-de-projetos, metodologia

"Acrescentar mais gente em um projeto de software atrasado resulta em um atraso ainda maior".

Porém quando sei que essa lei se aplica, para toda lei existe exceções.

As vezes um projeto realmente não está atrasado por falta de mão de obra qualificada?

Comment: Não sei se dá para responder isto. Acho mais fácil responder se o projeto vai atrasar ou não, o que já não é fácil. Pode haver sinais, mas se fossem óbvios ninguém cometeria esses erros. Mas até onde sei a questão é justamente não colocar mais gente sem qualificação e sim substituir por gente qualificada. Ou melhor ainda, começar com gente qualificada. Tem um problema em gente qualificada: ela vai dizer que não dá pra cumprir aquele prazo maluco inventado. Se toda lei tem exceções, algumas não terão :P Sei lá se essa tem ou não. Nem sei se esta pergunta pode ser considera *on-topic*.

Comment: Para cada pessoa nova no projeto, uma que já trabalha deve parar seu trabalho para explicar as dúvidas para os novatos.

Comment: Concordo com o @rray, e entendo seu ponto de vista bigown.
Porem eventualmente a pessoa contratada, deve passar por aquela curva de aprendizado e agregar valor ao desenvolvimento. e acho que essa era a discusão que queria levantar. Também não sei se é on-topic ou deveria ser feita no Project Management

Comment: Não é uma questão adequadamente classificada como **projeto-de-software** (*software design*). Remover esta marca facilitará a localização de questões.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existem vários diferentes pontos de vista quanto a cada aspecto de um projeto de software; e muitos destes pontos são muito bem embasados. Toda esta diversidade pode trazer a noção de que este é um assunto subjetivo onde nenhuma resposta está certa, nem errada.

No [livro onde Brooks propõe esta lei](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201835959), ela figura em meio a várias outras sentenças curtas, sem muita explicação. Mas esta sentença em si tem uma breve explicação logo no parágrafo seguinte:

> "Adicionar pessoas a um projeto de software aumenta o esforço total necessário de três maneiras: o trabalho de reparticionar o projeto e a perturbação que o reparticionamento causa, treinamento das novas pessoas, e o aumento do esforço em intercomunicação."

Sobre a comunicação em específico ele fala em outro parágrafo que quanto mais gente no projeto, maior o custo e maior a dificuldade da comunicação.

## Às vezes um projeto realmente não está atrasado por falta de mão de obra qualificada?

Talvez Brooks não tenha descartado este aspecto ao formular sua lei, pois no mesmo livro ele próprio menciona:

> "Programadores profissionais muito bons são dez vezes mais produtivos que programadores medianos*, com o mesmo treinamento e nível de experiência de dois anos."

<sub>*Aqui ele usa a palavra *"poor"*, que eu acho que seria melhor traduzida neste caso para "medíocre", mas fica a seu critério.</sub>

Se ele acredita nisso, por que formulou a lei? O projeto não poderia ser salvo trazendo pessoas mais qualificadas?

O problema talvez seja identificar as pessoas qualificadas. A menção não diz *"programadores mais qualificados"*, ela diz *"programadores muito bons, com a mesma experiência e treinamento"*. Ou seja: a rigor, com a mesma qualificação.

## Exceções à Lei de Brooks

**Ora, isto só é uma lei porque ele disse que é** :D Você pode aplicar as exceções que bem entender e provavelmente no próprio livro dele você vai encontrar texto que parece contradizer a lei.

Algumas exceções óbvias (fáceis de elaborar):

- Em vez de adicionar pessoas, você pode substituir, não adicionando custo de comunicação nem gestão.
- Você pode substituir por pessoas que já possuam o devido treinamento, sem adicionar este custo de tempo e dinheiro ao projeto.
- Você pode delegar trabalho já delimitado para as novas pessoas em vez de repartir o projeto.

Pelo que tenho lido e observado, todavia, nenhum projeto é devolvido à agenda pela simples substituição ou adição de desenvolvedores. O que tenho visto é que quando um projeto muda de rumo por ter havido substituições, a primeira substituição que ocorreu foi a da gestão do projeto.

E eu te alerto que você não vai encontrar muita literatura dizendo para pôr **pessoas mais qualificadas** no projeto a fim de trazê-lo de volta para a agenda, pois isso seria **transferir a culpa para o peão** (o programador) em vez de mantê-la no âmbito da gestão, o que é politicamente mais correto.